# how to find the difference between a csv file and a file containing only one column of this csv

Tags: diff, replace

I have a CSV file containing some user data it looks like this:

```
"10333","","an.10","Kenyata","","Aaron","","","","","","","","","",""
"12222","","an.4","Wendy","","Aaron","","","","","","","","","",""
"14343","","aaron.5","Nanci","","Aaron","","","","","","","","","",""
```

I also have a file which has an item on each line like this:

```
an.10
arron.5
```

What I want is to find only the lines in the CSV file contained in the list file.

So desired output would be:

```
"10333","","an.10","Kenyata","","Aaron","","","","","","","","","",""
"14343","","aaron.5","Nanci","","Aaron","","","","","","","","","",""
```

(Note how an.4 is not contained in this new list.)

I have any environment available to me and am willing to try just about anything aside from manually doing so as this csv contains millions of records and there are about 100k entries in the list itself.

Comment: Take a look at my FOSS tool CSVfix at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ - particularly the join command.

Comment: Which operating system? Do you have Excel available? Do you want a programming solution? Do you have tools like grep available?

Comment: I run fedora 12 and have linux boxes, also windows VMs. Grep, sed, diff, all are availabl. I prefer CLI solutions but am open to perl or whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How unique are the identifiers `an.10` and the like?

Maybe a very small *x shell script would be enough:

```
for i in $(uniq list.txt); do grep "\"$i\"" data.csv; done
```

That would, for every unique entry in the list, return all matching lines in the csv file. It does not match exclusively on the second column however. (That could be done with `awk` for example)

Comment: What a scary coincidence in the choice of file names! But your code will not work, $i will have only one value "list.txt".

Comment: This does not output the entire line from the csv file it only outputs the matched string and I am also receiving duplicate entries.

Comment: Another cause of duplicates could be a user an.10 matching a line like joan.100 - I have included the double quotes in the search term.

Answer (score 1):

If the csv file is data.csv and the list file is list.txt, I would do this:

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; do grep $i data.csv; done
```

Comment: im ending up with duplicates though ?

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your list then? If you want a quick fix to remove these, pipe either your list or the result through `|uniq`